# How can I determine the start up amps on a 3 phase 5 ton A/C unit?

Tags: hvac

I am trying to properly size a home generator and my concern is the start up amps on a 5 ton AC unit (15 years old R22 Goodwin type). My home power is unique because we have 3 phase (the AC is on 3 phase breaker). I think the line to line voltage is around 240 and the line to ground approx 120 but the stinger leg (whatever you call it) is approx 207V to ground. The generator folk say 118 amps start up but that seem high to me not sure if he is just multiplying the steady state amps or what? Can you tell me how to determine it?

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to use a clamp-on amp meter.  You will need to measure the current before the capacitors.  There are plenty of youtube videos on how to measure using that style of meter.

Comment: Also consider getting a hard start kit for the ac unit.  That will reduce startup load.

Answer (score 2):

For a hermetic compressor (what you most likely have in a unit of that size and vintage) -- the answer you seek is right on the compressor's nameplate, marked as "LRA", "Locked-Rotor Amps", under a "Locked Rotor" field, or in a similar fashion, as per NEC 440.4(A):

> The locked-rotor current of each single-phase motor-compressor having a 
>   rated-load current of more than 9 amperes at 115 volts, or more than 4.5 
>   amperes at 230 volts, and each polyphase motor-compressor shall be marked 
>   on the motor-compressor nameplate.

If you, somehow, have a compressor that uses an *external* motor drive, check the motor nameplate for the information from 430.7(B) point 8:

> (8) Code letter or locked-rotor amperes if an alternating-current motor 
>   rated 1/2 hp or more. On polyphase wound-rotor motors, the code letter 
>   shall be omitted.

(You'll also need Table 430.7(B) to interpret the code letters if your motor is marked that way.)